# Does database table namespacing exist?

Tags: database

I always wondered about one relevant (for me) but not existent feature of all the relational databases I worked with: the impossibility to namespace tables.

in MySQL, for example, you can fully qualify the table with the database name, such as `dbname.tablename`, with the database acting as a "prefix" or "namespace". However, this feature stops here, and does not take you very far. Namespace support would grant you the possibility to have a syntax like `dbname.namespace.table`. You could group related tables into different namespaces, such as (for a blog)

```
db.userdata.logininfo
db.userdata.preferences
db.postdata.content
db.postdata.acls
```

or

```
db.blog.whatever
db.wiki.whatever
db.common.auth
```

This would allow to stay within the same database (exploiting all the advantages of such setup) while at the same time granting a more flexible and self-documenting environment. Most of the time, however, I found that an underscore in the table name is used to serve this purpose as an apparent workaround.

My questions are : do DBMS with such feature exist (maybe with a different name)? is it deemed not important enough in database design practices to be granted support ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is called a **schema in SQL Server**. It was introduced in SQL Server 2005. Tables belong to schemas, and are referred to via dot notation, such as `owner.schema.tablename`, for example `dbo.HumanResources.Employee`.

[Here is one of many explanations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124894%28SQL.100%29.aspx) of the schema in AdventureWorks, which is a commonly-used sample database for SQL Server.

Now that you know that that is the name SQL Server uses, you can find plenty of information about it. Here are a couple of articles providing some insight into the benefits of this feature:

[Benefit from SQL Server 2005's new schema convention](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6104781.html)

[Security Enhancements in SQL Server 2005: Schema](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/authorization_2005_p1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server (2005+) has schemas which you can interpret as namespaces (see AdventureWorks samples).

In Oracle tables are always owned by a user, but table access can be granted to other users, so you can achieve similar functionality.

You might also use quoted identifiers (MS [], Oracle "") to use "namespace.name" naming schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a hierarchical namespace on database tables, but you can use schemas in SQL Server 2005+ to do this.  Similar constructs exist in other DBMS platforms as well.

Oracle has a module scope for stored procedure code (called packages) which gives you module level name spaces for code.  Nothing equivalent exists in T-SQL, although stored procedures can live in schemas.